# Undo insertion and deletion in one step when undoing overwrite of selection

Tags: undo, deletion, selection, delete-selection-mode

Undoing the insertion of a character while the region is active (and `delete-selection-mode` is non-nil) requires two steps: the first to undo the insertion and the second to restore the deleted region. Is it possible to undo both steps with a single call to `undo` instead?

Comment: Just curious: Why would you want `undo` to (always) do that? Do you never want to just undo the insertion? (The defined behavior lets you undo only the insertion or undo both the insertion and the deletion.)

Comment: @Drew You've got a point. But in the end I usually want to undo both steps at once. I see it as one operation and it still catches me kind of off guard that I need to undo again after the first time.

Comment: Hopefully someone will provide a good answer as to how to provide this, then.